# Detecting text with ARSKView and Vision

Tags: ios, sprite-kit, avfoundation, arkit, apple-vision

I have a view controller with an `ARSKView` whose `ARSession` I configure like this:

```
let configuration = ARWorldTrackingSessionConfiguration()
arskView.session.run(configuration)
```

In its associated `SKScene` I have this method implementation:

```
override func update(_ currentTime: TimeInterval) {
    guard let arskView = self.view as? ARSKView else {
        return
    }

    if let currentFrame = arskView.session.currentFrame {
       let capturedImage = currentFrame.capturedImage
       var requestOptions: [VNImageOption : Any] = [:]

       if let cameraData = CMGetAttachment(capturedImage, kCMSampleBufferAttachmentKey_CameraIntrinsicMatrix, nil) {
          requestOptions = [.cameraIntrinsics : cameraData]
       }

       let request = VNDetectTextRectanglesRequest { [weak self] (request, error) in
          self?.detectTextHandler(request: request, error: error)
       }
       request.reportCharacterBoxes = true

       let imageRequestHandler = VNImageRequestHandler(cvPixelBuffer: capturedImage, orientation: 6, options: requestOptions)

       do {
          try imageRequestHandler.perform([request])
       } catch {
          print(error)
       }
    }
}
```

Then, some logic to draw rectangles wrapping the detected text. I found such logic in [this article](http://www.appcoda.com/vision-framework-introduction/), where `ARKit` and thus `ARSKView` are not used, but `AVCaptureSession` and `AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer` instead. When you run that example, the camera has better quality and text boxes are more accurately drawn than when I run my project using `ARKit` and `ARSKView`.

I need to use `ARKit` with `SpriteKit`, but when I move the camera close to texts they are shown blurred, and in general the boxes wrapping words are drawn quite misplaced.

Is there any way I could improve this?

Comment: Is your text and image? If so, maybe check the size of the image. Perhaps it is smaller than you need and it just gets blurry because you are stretching the text's image.

Comment: @BrandonA no, I'm directly running the `ARSKView`'s session, what I see is the camera live stream

Comment: I have the same issue, any help please :S